# Ctrl + / Does not work in SCSS/SASS files to comment code in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't get `ctrl` + `/` to work in scss files in Visual studio 2017. It works in regular CSS files but not in scss/sass/less files.

How can I set this up, I don't know if I'm missing an obvious setting here.

Comment: I don't think VS has scss support by default. I believe I used to use this add-on: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

Comment: That add-on is for compiling it to CSS. Which i already do with gulp.js so I don't need that. It also doesn't add the ctrl + / functionality

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? It also does not work on .css files.

Comment: No I did not find a solution. Sorry